# Change placeholder text every two seconds in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the set state value every `two` seconds and can run in a loop but that does not seem to work with the below logic.

Excerpt from my code

```
 const placeholderText = ["one", "two", "three"];
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    placeholderText.map((val, index) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setState(placeholderText[index]);
      }, 2000)
    );
  }, []);

  console.log(state);
```

When I try to console log the `state`, I get three values at a time after two seconds. How can I set the state every two seconds and run it in a loop so that it keeps changing?

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-hoover-6vy8w?file=/src/App.js:109-383). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`.

Also, we can simplify the implementation in such a way that, we don't have to store the actual text in the state, rather we can store the index. And update the same after the stipulated interval.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const placeholderText = ["one", "two", "three"];

const Test = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = () => {
      setIndex(prevIndex => {
        if(prevIndex === placeholderText.length - 1){
          return 0;
        } 
        return prevIndex + 1;
      })
    };
    setInterval(timer, 2000);
    
    //cleanup function in order clear the interval timer
    //when the component unmounts
    return () => { clearInterval(timer); }
  }, []);

  return <p>{placeholderText[index]}</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Here, in the example for the simplicity I have used `placeholderText` outside the component. This can be passed as prop to the component and use in the component like below and use the same as dependency to the `useEffect` hook.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Test text={placeholderText}/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 1):

You are scheduling them all at the same time so they appear at the same time 2 secs later. I would do it like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const delayExecution = (mls) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("ok"), mls);
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const placeholderText = ["one", "two", "three"];
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const changePlaceholder = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < placeholderText.length; i++) {
      await delayExecution(2000);
      setState(placeholderText[i]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changePlaceholder();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" placeholder={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`delayExecution` resolves a promise after a set number of millisecs and thus can be awaited. The async function `changePlaceholder` does the rest.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-worker-4v4yc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Great! But, this would stop changing the placeholder text once it reached the end of the array.

Comment: @scriobh Indeed. Wish you pointed out that you want to keep looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval instead of setTimeout to update the text in every 2 seconds. Something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const placeholderText = ["one", "two", "three"];
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setState((s) => (s + 1));
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  const placeholder = placeholderText[state % placeholderText.length]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {placeholder}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because of closure. If you want to change in each 2s . You need `setInterval` not `setTimeout`. One way to tackle this use IIFE function so that it uses each loop value in `setInterval` instead of loop final one. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const placeholderText = ["one", "two", "three"];
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setState(function (prev) {
        if (prev === 2) {
          setState(0);
        } else {
          setState(prev + 1);
        }
      });
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      interval && clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(placeholderText, state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {placeholderText[state]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-swirles-83d8m?file=/src/App.js:0-718

Comment: fixed for you https://codesandbox.io/s/old-dust-jv4q5

Comment: Yes thanks. Technically there is no loop required if we are using `setInterval`